# how do I vertically align the logo.png and the text

Tags: css, navbar, valign

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
   <div class="container">
       <a class="navbar-brand wrapText" href="#stage"><span><img src="img/icon.png" width="24px"/>&nbsp;SCOTTIESCOTSMAN</span></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle ="collapse" data-target = "mainNavBar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#service">SERVICES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#project">PROJECTS</a>
                </li>              
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#blog">BLOG</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

how do I vertically align the logo.png and the text ...and my icon bars don't work as in no menu appears on click.
 ... sorry newbie :)

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a couple of different things because I was not entirely sure what you were looking for so I added a few fiddles comment below my answer if they are not what you are looking for because I wasn't sure by your question what you were looking to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your image to be the background for your text you can just set the image to be the background for the .navbar-brand and then set the size in your css like so:

```
.navbar-brand{
  background:url('http://placehold.it/25x25');
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: 24px 24px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle to show you this in action [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/vvL88ct4/)

If you want your text and image to appear like they are on the same line like your image is bigger than the text add a line height to the image like so:

```
.navbar-brand img{
  width:24px;
  line-height:50px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Here is a fiddle for that [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/bh4kt630/)

Also your missing a div in your navbar you should have the navbar-brand and the the responsive button wrapped in a div called navbar-header.  Then to get your menu to open your data-target in your button should read #mainNavbar your missing the #.  Your navbar should look like the following:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar-header">
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#stage">SCOTTIESCOTSMAN</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle ="collapse" data-target = "#mainNavBar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
       </div>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#service">SERVICES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#project">PROJECTS</a>
                </li>              
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#blog">BLOG</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks for the iconbar fix m8. but i don't want the text to look on the same line  eg. icon height 24px text height 14px so be margin top 5 and bottom 5 so text is centred in the middle of the .png .. hope that helps

Comment: its not centred vertivaly with the img. i think i need to take the text out of the navbar brand for it to work :( grr

Answer (score -1):

Try `vertical-align: middle` on the logo image class?

Comment: sorry didn't work ... thanks for trying. so simple I cant do it lol ... text in the middle of a picture?

Comment: ah text in the middle of the picture. this might work.
`.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}`

Comment: the text is obviously smaller than the icon  ... but want it centred vertically... ta!